# How to convert a vector of vectors into a DataFrame in Julia, without for loop?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I created a Vector of Vectors, named `all_arrays` in Julia in this way for a specific purpose:

```
using DataFrames
using StatsBase

list_of_numbers = 1:17

all_arrays = [zeros(Float64, (17,)) for i in 1:1000]
round = 1
while round != 1001
    random_array = StatsBase.sample(1:17 , length(list_of_numbers))
    random_array = random_array/sum(random_array)

    if (0.0 in random_array) || (random_array in all_arrays)
        continue
    end

    all_arrays[round] = random_array
    round += 1
    println(round)
end
```

The dimension of `all_arrays` is:

```
julia> size(all_arrays)
(1000,)
```

Then I want to convert `all_arrays` into a DataFrame with 1000*17 dimensions (Note that each vector in the `all_arrays` is a (17,) shape Vector). I tried This way:

```
df = DataFrames.DataFrame(zeros(1000,17) , :auto)
for idx in 1:length(all_arrays)
    df[idx , :] = all_arrays[idx]
end
```

But I'm looking for a straightforward way for this instead of a for loop and a prebuilt DataFrame! Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want simple code use (the length of the code is the same as below, but I find it conceptually simpler):

```
DataFrame(mapreduce(permutedims, vcat, all_arrays), :auto)
```

For such small data as you described this should be efficient enough.

If you want something faster use:

```
DataFrame([getindex.(all_arrays, i) for i in 1:17], :auto, copycols=false)
```

Here is a benchmark:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime DataFrame(mapreduce(permutedims, vcat, $all_arrays), :auto);
  7.257 ms (3971 allocations: 65.22 MiB)

julia> @btime DataFrame([getindex.($all_arrays, i) for i in 1:17], :auto, copycols=false);
  41.000 μs (88 allocations: 140.66 KiB)
```

Comment: Thanks! I specified that I want to avoid using for loops and a prebuilt DataFrame; instead, I want a straightforward way to do this, like a shorter code. And the answer is precisely what I expected.

Comment: Sure - I just was not sure if performance was your objective :). As performance is usually what Julia users ask for. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sure it is! I want higher performance when I avoid `for` loops! And let me tell you smth. I wrote this code in Python and ran it on the Colab. It took more than 1 Hour in Python. But in Julia, it took 0.7 seconds runtime on my machine! It's fascinating!!!

Comment: Wait... if the reason "to avoid for loops" is looking for performance, this is not correct. Indeed in Julia `for` loops have (roughly) the same efficiency than vectorised code. Just use the form that is more intuitive for you/the algorithm. Still there are in Julia possible performance pitfails .Have a look to [these tips](https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/stable/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0106_-_Further_topics.html#Some-performance-tips)

Comment: @Antonello, I didn't know that! Thanks! Anyway, I'm satisfied with the one-line short form of code instead of four lines.

Comment: `for` loop is fast if it does not use global variables. The OP solution used global variable, which was slowing it down. One would either need to wrap all in a function, use `let` or define global variables as `const` or in Julia 1.8 or later provide type assertions for them.